# How to do if/and comparisons in jinja template from python flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

Im trying to highlight cell blocks in a html table in a flask web app. I am passing the variables created in python:
fnowdate = 04-03-2021
fday90 = 07-02-2021

I'm trying to use a if statement with a "and" comparison to evaluate if the date is greater than today date and less than 90 days from now.

This is my code below, what is wrong here, can I not use "and" in the if statement?

```
<td {% if result.Expiration_Date >= {{"fnowdate"}} and result.Expiration_Date <= {{"fday90"}} %}style="background-color:red;"{% endif %}>{{ result.Expiration_Date }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
    .bg-red{
        background-color:red;
    }
<style/>

<td class='{{"bg-red" if result.Expiration_Date >= fnowdate  and result.Expiration_Date <= fday90 }}'>
    {{ result.Expiration_Date }}
</td>
```